# Python CSV files processing with sub categories

Tags: python, csv

In my Python application, I'm saving values from various fields into a text file and I decided to go with a CSV format so that I can open it in Excel in a readable way.  I can also modify the values in the file and import these in the app.  The format in the file looks like this:

```
Category 1, Param 1, Param 2, Param 3, Param 4
Command 1, 100, 123, 456, 1000
Command 2, 980, 312, 567, 882
Command 3, 0, 111, 584, 223
Category 2, Param A, Param B, Param C
Command A, 24, 14, 66
Command B, 59, 0, 123
```

Saving the CSV file is not much of a problem but what I'm wondering is how to separate the categories, as I don't have the same amount of parameters for each one.  I've been using the `csv` module of Python and the `DictReader` method but it just grabs everything and put it in the same basket.  So, for instance, if I use this code:

```
def parseCsvFile(self, paramsfile):
    with open(paramsfile, 'rb') as csvfile:
        paramNames = ['Category', 'Param 1', 'Param 2', 'Param 3', 'Param 4']
        paramsReader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=paramNames)
        for row in paramsReader:
            print row['Category']
```

I will get this result:

```
Category 1
Command 1
Command 2
Command 3
Category 2
Command A
Command B
```

Is there a way to retrieve the data of Category 1 in a first time and then Category 2 with another set of fieldnames?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't understand the expected output. Please update with what `Category 1` should produce

Comment: why not use a single file for each category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the real problem is that `csv.DictReader` really isn't designed for this sort of file.  In particular, it assumes that the same dictionary should be used to address each line throughout the file.  But you're changing the type of line midway through.  Instead, you should just use `csv.reader`.

I'm guessing you still want to address your data as a dictionary; in that case, you just need to create the dictionary yourself.  I'm also guessing you want the data processed as integers; if not replace `int` below with the relevant thing.  The following does what I think you want:

```
def parseCsvFile(self, paramsfile) :
    import csv
    csvDict = {}
    category = 'Unknown Category'
    params = []
    with open(paramsfile, 'rb') as csvfile :
        paramsReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in paramsReader :
            if row[0].startswith('Category') :
                category = row[0]
                csvDict[category] = {}
                params = [p.strip() for p in row[1:] if p]
            else :
                csvDict[category][row[0]] = dict(zip(params, [int(p) for p in row[1:] if p]))
    return csvDict
```

The returned dictionary csvDict will be a nested dictionary.  Each section of the file will be a key in the dictionary, and the corresponding item will be another dictionary holding each of the lines from that section as a dictionary.

Comment: I just have a small issue caused by Excel which adds empty values at the end of the Category 2 lines.  Running your code result in: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`.  But manually removing the extra commas in the CSV file makes it work as expected.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked!  It's actually also easy to get it to ignore the extra columns from Excel.  I've added `if p` to the second-to-last line of the code, which does the job.